# Trouble in one of the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am having one stored procedure wherein I am having some difficulties in one condition.

How to write this in 1 condition, basically if I remove everything from **AND** it works fine, but I also wanted to add one more condition so that if the count of the rows is `> 0` only then so inside the loop.

How to do that can anyone have any idea.

This is my actual SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Insert__DDL_Records_Into_FinalTable]
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SQLTableDet VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLInsDet VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DelSQLTableDet VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @DestDB VARCHAR(20)

SET @DestDB = 'DB_Audit'
SET @Table_Name ='t_ddl_log'

DECLARE Database_Details CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name   
FROM 
sys.databases 
WHERE
database_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4) 
AND 
name <> 'DB_Audit' AND name <> 'DemoFatalCorruption1' AND name <>    'AdventureWorks' AND name <> 'AdventureWorks2008R2_Old' AND name <> 'AdventureWorks2008R2'

OPEN Database_Details

FETCH NEXT FROM Database_Details INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF (OBJECT_ID(+ @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name) IS NOT NULL) 

AND ('SELECT CAST (COUNT(*) AS varchar(20)) FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name) > '0'
BEGIN
    SET @SQLTableDet = ' INSERT INTO '+ @DestDB + '.dbo.'+ @Table_Name + 
                       ' SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name   

    PRINT @SQLTableDet

    SET @SQLInsDet  = 'USE [' + @DBName + ']' + @SQLTableDet
    PRINT @SQLInsDet
    EXEC (@SQLInsDet)

    SET @DelSQLTableDet = 'DELETE FROM ' +  @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name 
    PRINT @DelSQLTableDet
    EXEC (@DelSQLTableDet)  
END     


FETCH NEXT FROM Database_Details INTO @DBName
PRINT @DBName

END  
CLOSE Database_Details  
DEALLOCATE Database_Details
END
```

And I have a problem under this line

```
 IF (OBJECT_ID(+ @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name) IS NOT NULL) 
AND ('SELECT CAST (COUNT(*) AS varchar(20)) FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.' +   @Table_Name) > '0'
```

Wherein If the count is greater than 0 only then move forward, but some how It is going inside the loop even if count is 0

Answer (score 1):

You can split the query into two.

The **first** `IF` checks for the table existence and the **second** `IF` checks any row existence of the underlying table:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(+ @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name) IS NOT NULL) 
    IF EXISTS ('SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name)
```

You may add `BEGIN` ... `END` for each `IF` for better readability and not cause any confusion.

Comment: It gives me an error " An expression for non boolean type specified.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the last parenthesis in the IF statement will solve your problem.

Change the code for the IF statement as follows:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(+ @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name) IS NOT NULL) 
AND ('SELECT CAST (COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(20)) FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.' + 
@Table_Name) > 0
```

Comment: Even tough it is not giving me any error now, but it is still going inside the loop where the count is 0

Comment: Now is time to give us a little more information about what you are trying to do and the code after the if statement. What is your expected output?

Comment: I am creating a store procedure for Audit wherein if any of the database has 0 entries it should not go inside the loop because then it is taking lot of unnecessary time. So what I was trying to do is I am checking in a condition if the count is greater than 0 only then go inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

May be this is a bit lengthy - but working solution:

```
DECLARE @DBName varchar(50)
DECLARE @Table_Name varchar(50)
DECLARE @ConditionIsTrue BIT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DBName = 'tempdb'
SET @Table_Name = 'MyTestTable'
SET @ConditionIsTrue = 0

SET @SQL = '
IF (OBJECT_ID(+ @DBName + ''.dbo.'' + @Table_Name) IS NOT NULL) 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.' + @Table_Name + ')
    SET @ConditionIsTrue = 1 '
Execute sp_executesql @SQL, N'@DBName VARCHAR(50), @Table_Name VARCHAR(50), @ConditionIsTrue BIT OUTPUT', @DBName, @Table_Name, @ConditionIsTrue OUTPUT
SELECT @ConditionIsTrue
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute dynamic query first, then check its result.
You should use `QuoteName` to avoid sql injection.

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ' + QuoteName(@DBName) + '.dbo.' + QuoteName(@Table_Name)

EXEC sp_executesql @query
DECLARE @RowCount int = @@ROWCOUNT


IF (
    OBJECT_ID(QuoteName(@DBName)  + '.dbo.' + QuoteName(@Table_Name)) IS NOT NULL 
    AND  @RowCount > 0
)
BEGIN
    -- Do stuff..........
END
```